# How to add a line to @"https:\\something_like_this.com\Data\text.txt"

Tags: c#, sharepoint, https, append

I'd like to add a line of text to a text file on a SharePoint folder.
Here's what I tried (Please assume that `text.txt` already exists):

```
using System.IO;

namespace WriteText
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"https:\\something_like_this.com\Data\text.txt";
            //string path = @"C:\Data\text.txt";
            File.AppendAllLines( path, new[]{"Hello"});
        }
    }
}
```

... However, I got `System.NotSupportedException`.
When I copy `https:\\something_like_this.com\Data\text.txt` and paste to a browser,
I can see the file content. It means that the URL is correct.
Why can't I add a line to the text file?

Incidentally, if the path is `@"C:\Data\text.txt"`, it succeeds to add a line.

This is so simple, but how can I fix this?
Could anyone try my code to add a line to a text file on a `https:\\your_own_server.com\...`?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to download the file to your local machine first then append it?  You cant use `File.IO` to modify files on the internet

Comment: @maccettura No, I didn't, but it seems there is no way other than downloading the file from SharePoint and then append it.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Yes, kind of, thank you. However, willman's answer is a better start for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to programmatically log in to SharePoint through the API, then download the file, then make your change to the file, then upload it back to SharePoint.

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, you will first want to install the nuget package appropriate for your version of SharePoint ([2013](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2013.CSOM/), [2016](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2016.CSOM/), [2019](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2019.CSOM/), [Online/O365](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM)).

Then try something like this:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{ 
  var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle); 
  var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId); 
  clientContext.Load(list);
  clientContext.Load(listItem, i => i.File); 
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
  var fileRef = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl; 
  var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef); 
  var fileName = Path.Combine(filePath, (string)listItem.File.Name); 
  using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create())
  { 
    fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
  } 
  File.AppendAllLines(fileName, new[]{"Hello"}); }

  using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
  {
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef, fs, true);
  }
}
```

Note that if your library requires checkout, you may also need to programmatically check-out the file before uploading your changed file, then checking it back in.

Comment: I'm working on yours. I already downloaded SharePoint's CSOM. It's a big hint. Thank you. Although some pieces are missing in your code, I'm filling those parts now. Please wait (for a day or two).